# How get data from WCF by using reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection

I want to try create multiple WCF services. They will return `List<BaseObjectType>` or `IQueryable<baseObjectType>`.

`BaseObjectType` is parent for some object (like `Person`, `Invoice`, `Document`, .....)
So WCF service can return `List<BaseObjectType>` but if it is necessary, it can return for example `List<Person>`, `List<Invoice>` etc.....

I want to create universal grid, which will have string property SourceType for reflection.

Is it possible to create method, which will call WCF service by using reflection and populate grid with `List<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the KnownTypes attribute for each subclass of your base contract and then WCF will know how to serialize and deserialize the contracts correctly. Reflection wouldn't really be needed on the client side since the deserialized types would be of the correct type.

Please see
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601224/What-is-KnownType-Attribute-and

Service definition

```
public void IService{
    List<BaseObject> GetObjects();
}

[DataContract]
[KnownTypes(typeof(DerivedObject))]
public class BaseObject(){
    [DataMember]
    public void string BaseProperty{get;set;}
}
public class DerivedObject:BaseObject(){
    [DataMember]
    public void string DerivedProperty{get;set;}
}
```

in Client code

```
var s = new Service();
var objects = s.GetObjects();
//objects can contain both DerivedObjects or BaseObjects
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics aren't supported in WCF this way. It really would be nice if it was, because I've come across a few scenarios where it would be great to have the client pass a generic argument to the server. Unfortunately if you use a generic in an OperationContract definition, WCF throws a WouldBeNiceButNotHappeningException at runtime.